# Subsets and Arbitrary Unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, he asserts that

*A* $\subseteq$ *B* $\Rightarrow$ $\bigcup$*A* $\subseteq$ $\bigcup$*B*

I don't believe that this is true, or at least from the way I've been trying to prove this.

Let *A* = {*a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>*} be a set containing *n* elements, all of which are also sets.

And let *B* = { {*a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>*}, *b<sub>1</sub>*, *b<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *b<sub>m</sub>*} be a set containing *m + 1* elements, all of which are also sets.

Let it be known here that the first condition is true: *A* $\subseteq$ *B*

$\bigcup$*A* = {elements of *a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>*} by definition, and

$\bigcup$*B* = {*a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>*, elements of *b<sub>1</sub>*, *b<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *b<sub>m</sub>*}

Is $\bigcup$*A* $\subseteq$ $\bigcup$*B*?

I don't think so. Let *x* $\in$ $\bigcup$*A*. Therefore, *x* is an element of some *a<sub>i</sub>* in *a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>*. The elements of *a<sub>1</sub>*, *a<sub>2</sub>*, $\ldots$ , *a<sub>n</sub>* $\notin$ $\bigcup$*B*, therefore

*x* $\notin$ $\bigcup$B

$\bigcup$*A* $\subseteq$ $\bigcup$*B* must be false.

Am I right? If not, how should I be approaching this?

Comment: Do you sure that $A \subset B$?

Comment: The theorem is $A\subseteq B\implies \bigcup A\subseteq \bigcup B$.  Showing $\bigcup A\subseteq \bigcup B$ for some sets where $A\nsubseteq B$ doesn't disprove the theorem.

Comment: Your $A$ and $B$ don't satisfy the hypothesis of the assertion, so the conclusion needn't follow.

Comment: Also, inclusion ($\in$) and subset ($\subseteq$) are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your line of reasoning is that $A\in B$ but $A\not\subseteq B$.  The theorem as stated is true.